# Dialogflow with Lambda - Webhook call failed. Error: 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am using aws lambda to respond to a Dialogflow webhook via API gateway. I have added the webhook in fulfillment using basic auth. The lambda is successfully called (based on Cloudfront logs) and it returns a fulfillment_text response;

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    return { fulfillmentText: 'IT WORKS' };
};
```

For some reason, I always get:

API RESPONSE

> ```
>   "webhookStatus": {
>     "code": 13,
>     "message": "Webhook call failed. Error: 502 Bad Gateway."
>   }
> ```

[Dialogflow documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/fulfillment-how#webhook_response)

Comment: I have followed the directions at https://medium.com/faun/building-chatbot-with-google-dialogflow-with-aws-lambda-e19872e1589 and used the dialogflow fulfillment library with expresss. I was hoping to avoid using so many libraries and just handle json, but it works...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to pull it off w/out the need for express. I hope this helps.

```
{
    const { dialogflow,SimpleResponse,BasicCard,Image,Suggestions,MediaObject,SignIn,Permission } = require('actions-on-google');

    const app = dialogflow({debug:true, clientId: process.env.dialogFlowClientID});

    app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', (conv) => {
        conv.ask('You made it you rock star');
    });


    exports.lambdaHandler = app
}
```